# Kiwi spying on multiple NSNotifications

Tags: objective-c, nsnotification, kiwi

I am currently spying on `postNotification` like this

```
__block KWCaptureSpy *notificationSpy = [[NSNotificationCenter 
defaultCenter] captureArgument:@selector(postNotification:) atIndex:0];
```

The problem is I have multiple notifications with different notification names. How do I access the spy's argument for different notification.

For instance say I have Notification1 and Notification2 the spy argument captures Notification1 but I'm not able to capture the Notification2.

Any ideas of how this can be done?

Comment: I noticed you unacepted my answer, did something change and the answer no longer responds to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches come into my mind:

- `stub` the `sendNotification:` method, and build an array with the sent notifications:

  ```
  NSMutableArray *sentNotifications = [NSMutableArray array];        
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] stub:@selector(postNotification:) withBlock:^id(NSArray *params) {
      NSNotification *notification = params[0];
      [sentNotifications addObject:notification.name];
      return nil;
  }];
  [[sentNotifications shouldEventually] equal:@[@"TestNotification1", @"TestNotification2"]];
  ```

  if the notifications are not always sent in the same order, you might need another matcher then the `equal:` one.
- write a custom matcher that registers as observer and evaluates when asked about the received notifications:

  ```
  @interface MyNotificationMatcher : KWMatcher
  - (void)sendNotificationNamed:(NSString*)notificationName;
  - (void)sendNotificationsNamed:(NSArray*)notificationNames;
  @end
  ```

  which can be used in your tests like this:

  ```
  [[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] shouldEventually] sendNotificationsNamed:@[@"TestNotification1", @"TestNotification2"]];
  ```

As a side note, you don't need to decorate the `notifications` variable with `__block`, as you don't need to change the content of that variable (i.e. the pointer value).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was

```
__block NSMutableArray *notifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] stub:@selector(postNotification:) withBlock:^id(NSArray *params) {
            [notifications addObject:params[0]];
            return nil;
        }];
```